# Youtube video id (or URL) to "user" and "channel"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-channels

Given a URL or ID of a Youtube video, is it possible to get the (1) name of the "user" who had uploaded it and (2) channel that it belongs to? If so, what is the API request?

So, for example: lets' say I have a video ID: "VulCl5QfewE" corresponding to the video at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VulCl5QfewE

1. I then want to extract the name of the user, which is: "TheYoungTurks" and the URL of the user is:
   https://www.youtube.com/user/TheYoungTurks
2. I also want to be able to extract the name of the channel, which is: "UC1yBKRuGpC1tSM73A0ZjYjQ" and the URL of the channel is:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1yBKRuGpC1tSM73A0ZjYjQ

Finally, (as a "side, ancillary question") I am a bit confused what is the difference between a "channel" and a "user". Can a user have multiple channels? I did read the link here: https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/2vsyit/whats_the_difference_between_user_and_channel/ but I am trying to understand the use case behind it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the channel informations from a videoId, you need to use the ressource [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with the parameters:

```
part: snippet
id: "VulCl5QfewE" //for example

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=VulCl5QfewE&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The result show you the channelID of the user:

```
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/IcNtD4uunskZTQuIeM0YQRcc5HY\"",
   "id": "VulCl5QfewE",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-08-05T01:11:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC1yBKRuGpC1tSM73A0ZjYjQ",
```

Then use this information to get the name of the channel with the ressource `channel.list`

```
part: snippet
id: UC1yBKRuGpC1tSM73A0ZjYjQ

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UC1yBKRuGpC1tSM73A0ZjYjQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Part of the result:

```
  "snippet": {
    "title": "The Young Turks",
    "description": "The Largest Online News Show in the World. Hosted by Cenk Uygur & Ana Kasparian. LIVE weekdays 6-8pm ET. \n\nYoung Turk (n), 1. Young progressive or insurgent member of an institution, movement, or political party. 2. Young person who rebels against authority or societal expectations. (American Heritage Dictionary)\n\nThe Young Turks were the first original talk show on Sirius satellite radio and the first live, daily webcast on the internet. But that is not the revolution.\n\nWe are a rare show that combines all of the news that people care about in one place. We are not afraid to talk about politics and entertainment and sports and pop culture. But that is not the revolution either. \n\nGet The Young Turks\u200b Mobile App Today! \n\nDownload the iOS version here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-young-turks/id412793195? \n\nDownload the Android version here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tyt",
    "publishedAt": "2005-12-21T20:46:51.000Z",
```

> Finally, (as a "side, ancillary question") I am a bit confused what is
>   the difference between a "channel" and a "user". Can a user have
>   multiple channels? I did read the link here:
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/2vsyit/whats_the_difference_between_user_and_channel/
>   but I am trying to understand the use case behind it.

There is a link with Google+ account, check https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/3MsBApaK2Hw

Comment: To put some context, given a video, I am trying to get the 5 most recent uploads by that user. So what u are saying is if I get 5 most recent uploads from the channel, it is the same? In any case, is there a way to get the user name because the above example has both the username and channel name.

Comment: "is there a way to get the user name" ? i give you the method, i don't understant this question. "5 most recent uploads" use `video.list` with the channelID of the channel